# jQuery effects without using display: none

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am creating a webpage using jQuery and jQuery UI. Most of the elements fade in when they come into the viewport, this works fine. However, I have one problem.

For the elements to fade, they have to start invisible, so I added `display: none` to them. When they fade in though, they change the size of the containing div.

This is a problem because I have a custom smooth scrolling function to take you to a section of the page slowly (rather than instantly with links). It works by detecting the offset of the target element from the top of the page. As you scroll down and elements fade in, they make the page longer and therefore change the offset of the target element, resulting in the scrolling stopping before the target element is in view.

Is there any way to allow elements to be animated in, however start off without `display: none`?

NOTE: **I cannot use `opacity`! Please don't post an answer with this!** I use more advanced effects like `Fold` and `Slide In`, which cannot be achieved with opacity. Also, I have not posted code because I am asking if jQuery has any arguments to not use `display: none`

Comment: Would using `opacity:0` instead of `display:none` be an option?

Comment: Not really, I use other effects as well as fadeIn, for instance the [Fold effect](https://api.jqueryui.com/fold-effect/). Using `opacity` would be a serve restriction in the sorts of animations I can do.

Comment: Maybe you can post some code here...

Comment: Of what exactly? (Though I know I should). What I have done so far is pointless because it does not help in answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually decided to do the following:

- Set CSS for element to `visibility: hidden`
- When page loads, create new element directly after animated element, with a fixed width and height (the same as the animated element). This acts as a placeholder
- Set CSS for element to `display: none` and `visibility: visible` (the element has `display: none` so it cannot be seen)

Then when the element needs to be animated

- Remove placeholder using `.remove()`
- Start animation on element (therefore removing `display: none`)

So basically it creates a placeholder for the element. The placeholder contains nothing, it just has a fixed with and height. Then, when it is time to animate the element, remove the element and start the animation.

This is not the cleanest way to do it, but it works. You can also create a function to create the placeholder (even edit it and change the CSS too), passing the element to animate as one argument, and whether to create or remove a placeholder as the second:

```
function placeholder(element, action) {
    // CREATE PLACEHOLDER
    if (action == 'create') {
        var width = $(element).css('width') // To get 'px` on the end use .css()
        var height = $(element).css('height')

        // Create placeholder
        $('<div style"width: ' + width + '; height: ' + height + ;'"></div>')
        .insertAfter(element)
    }

    // REMOVE PLACEHOLDER
    if (action == 'remove') {
        // Remove placeholder
        $(element).next().remove()
    }
}

// CALLING THE FUNCTION
placeholder($('#element'), 'create')
placeholder($('#element'), 'remove')
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It pointed me in the right direction for my solution. That was, to create a parent element (with `position: relative;`) for _myDivToShow_. Then, as a sibling of _myDivToShow_ (which has `display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; top: 0;`), I created _myHiddenDiv_ (which has `visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; top: 0;`) with exactly the same content as _myDivToShow_ in order to ensure the rendering doesn't jump around while _myDivToShow_ is being rendered by jQuery UI's show() function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an element to be invisible yet still count in defining it's parent size, you should use CSS opacity property and set it to 0 (the opacity takes parameter between 0 and 1).

```
selector {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

But flamur is right you might want to post a bit of code here ...

Comment: Create a stacksnippet that demonstrates what the probem is if you start with opacity:0;

Comment: I cannot use this since I use other effects such as fold